# Create Db sequence with dynamic seq name

Tags: spring-data

I would like to create method in spring CrudRepository to create db seq with seq name as a parameter but it doesn't work when I try to pass parameter

```
@Query(value = "CREATE SEQUENCE if not exists :sequenceName START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1", nativeQuery = true)
  void createSequence(@Param("sequenceName") String sequenceName);
```

But it works when I do sth like

```
@Query(value = "CREATE SEQUENCE if not exists table_1_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1", nativeQuery = true)
  void createSequence();
```

Could you tell me how I can obtain it and why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunelly I didn't find certain definition in a [Spring Data reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference), but it is obvious that JPA only supports parameters in certain clauses within the query, not in DDL. So:

**first**: if you **really** tend to use dynamic DDL, use concatination to build SQL and then execute it by `jdbcTemplate.update` or `entityManager.createNativeQuery("..").executeUpdate()`

**second**: think, is it nesecessary use dynamic DDL? Use `Flyway` or `Liqubase` migrations instead to initialize the DB